# Issues Importing SP Metadata to SSOCircle Spring Security SAML Extention

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

I'm running the Spring Security SAML Extension sample program and I'm able to generate the Service Provider metadata.  However, when I try to import the SP metadata to SSOCircle, I get the following error:

> **Meta Data Import**
>
> Your data could not be imported 
>   Reason:
>
> DefaultValidationEventHandler: [FATAL_ERROR]: Unexpected end of
>   element {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}:Extensions Location:
>   line 4 Entity descriptor "localhost" under realm "/" has invalid
>   syntax.

I tried following the suggestions in this [post](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/saml/725846-metadata-import-to-ssocircle-not-working), but when I turn off discovery, it no longer shows the page and SSOCircle is shown and it says: **Error occurred** Reason: The SAML Request is invalid.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?  BTW, I'm using the 1.0.0.RELEASE version of the SAML Extension.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add the metadata you're importing into your question.

Comment: Hi, i don't know about you. but one thing to clarify with you is about SAML integration with spring security. Have you done SAML integration? because i stuck on that from 5 days. i have two web portals and i wanna integrate them to SAML i.e single sign on. am using spring mvc . i want to get saml with spring security . can you please tell me about that. thanks in advance –

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that property `includeDiscoveryExtension` is set to `false` on your `MetadataGenerator` bean. When enabled, this setting generates an `Extensions` element which is problematic with SSOCircle. Then verify that the generated metadata doesn't really include any `Extensions` element.

You might also be trying to import an SP with entity identifier which already exists in SSOCircle. So make sure to set a unique `entityId` for your SP by setting property `entityId` on `MetadataGenerator` bean to e.g. `urn:nualphaman:test`.

Comment: Setting the property `includeDiscoveryExtension` to false on the `MetadataGenerator` bean worked.  However, I had to click the **Download entity metadata** button and use that metadata for the import.  After doing a file comparison, I found that the only difference was the `entityId` was set with the value I set in the securityContext.xml instead of the generated value of localhost.

Comment: The includeDiscoveryExtension  property appears to be false by default after perusing the source code.  version=1.0.2